# Dummy Encoding for Date(time) in Python 3.7

Tags: python, performance, datetime, encoding

i wanted to create a function that encodes the month of a date(time) object into a season. So for example, if we have 2 seasons and the fourth month the function would return 0 as encoding. My question is now how to create such a function that it is most efficient but also pythonic (less lines of code). I came up with 3 different approaches, the first one looks like this:

```py
def seasonal_encoding(month: int, seasons):
    assert 12 % seasons == 0, "Seasons must be in [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12]"
    if seasons == 1:
        return _one_season()
    elif seasons == 2:
        return _two_seasons(month)
    elif seasons == 3:
        return _three_seasons(month)
    elif seasons == 4:
        return _four_seasons(month)
    elif seasons == 6:
        return _six_seasons(month)
    elif seasons == 12:
        return _twelve_seasons(month)
```

where for example `three_seasons` looks like this:

```py
def _three_seasons(month):
    if month in range(1, 5):
        return 0
    elif month in range(5, 9):
        return 1
    elif month in range(9, 13):
        return 2
```

This is so far the fastest approach i came up with, but as you can imagine this may work for
a season encoding, but if we want to encode other date(time) attributes, for example hours, this becomes cumbersome real fast. So i came up with a second solution which is a little slower but has less lines of code:

```py
def for_loop_seasonal_encoding(month: int, seasons: int):
    assert 12 % seasons == 0, "Seasons must be in [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12]"

    if seasons != 12:
        stepsize = int(12 / seasons)
        for i in range(1, seasons+1):
            if month in range((i-1) * stepsize + 1, i * stepsize + 1):
                return i-1
    else:
        return month
```

I also had another solution with numpy before coming up with the for loop solution which i will add for reasons of completeness, but this was four times slower then the other solutions.

```py
def numpy_seasonal_encoding(month: int, seasons):
    assert 12 % seasons == 0, "Seasons must be in [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12]"
    arr = np.array(range(1, 13))
    reshaped_arr = arr.reshape(seasons, int(12 / seasons))
    return np.where(reshaped_arr == month)[0][0]
```

**So my Question would be**: Has anyone of you an idea how to make this as fast as the if representation but with way less lines of codes in "pure" python (so without resorting to Cython, numba etc., external packages like numpy are ok)?

This is the link to the .py file
[Python File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yKJgFd9286Of2-CpV0GnzSKHaamrG0Jr/view?usp=sharing)  that includes the function used for timing and the code. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: `(month - 1) * seasons // 12` should work but I don't know if it is the fastest solution.

Comment: yes this works perfectly, thank you =).